# PostgreSQL: Very high read IO on one of the servers

Tags: postgresql, replication, performance

We have two servers dedicated to PostgreSQL 11.3:

1. master (128Mb RAM, 16 core CPU, SSD) - all write queries and 65% of read queries
2. slave (64GB RAM, 12 core CPU, SSD) - 35% of read queries

For unknown reason, slave dies with giant CPU IO wait times (around 70%) as soon as we enable it, while master has 0.5% IO wait times and runs fine. `iotop` on slave is showing a lot of disk reads from postgresql processes with SELECT quries.

Configuration files:

**master (works great)**

```
max_connections = 100

# for replication 
wal_keep_segments = 100
wal_level = replica
max_wal_senders = 10
hot_standby = on
archive_mode = off

archive_command = 'cp %p /backups/pgsql-wal/%f'
max_standby_streaming_delay = 30s

# how much dedicated memory will be used by PostgreSQL for cache 
shared_buffers = 20GB

# estimate of the memory available for disk caching.
effective_cache_size = 80GB

# transaction commits very quickly because it will not wait for a WAL file to be flushed, but reliability is compromised
synchronous_commit = off

maintenance_work_mem = 2GB

checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
checkpoint_timeout = 5min

wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 256MB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 10GB
max_worker_processes = 16
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 8
max_parallel_workers = 16

# vacuum
vacuum_cost_limit = 1000
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 10
autovacuum_max_workers = 6


# io performance
effective_io_concurrency = 2
random_page_cost = 1.5
seq_page_cost = 1.0

shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'

track_activity_query_size = 10000
```

**slave (gets huge amount of disk read io)**

```
max_connections = 100

# for replication 
wal_keep_segments = 100
wal_level = replica
max_wal_senders = 10
hot_standby = on
hot_standby_feedback = on
archive_mode = off
archive_command = 'cp %p /backups/pgsql-wal/%f'
max_standby_streaming_delay = 30s

# how much dedicated memory will be used by PostgreSQL for cache 
shared_buffers = 10GB

# estimate of the memory available for disk caching.
effective_cache_size = 40GB

# transaction commits very quickly because it will not wait for a WAL file to be flushed, but reliability is compromised
synchronous_commit = off

maintenance_work_mem = 2GB

checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
checkpoint_timeout = 5min

wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
work_mem = 128MB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 10GB
max_worker_processes = 16
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 6
max_parallel_workers = 12


# io performance
effective_io_concurrency = 2
random_page_cost = 1.5
seq_page_cost = 1.0

shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'

# Increase the max size of the query strings Postgres records
track_activity_query_size = 10000
```

Any ideas what parameters are miconfigured on slave?

Comment: Could you give us a diff between the configuration files? What is the operating system on both systems? If Linux, which I/O scheduler are you using on each system? If Linux, did you disable "transparent hugepages" on both systems? Are the queries the same or similar on both systems? Can you isolate a single query that performs well on one and badly on the other system, or do you observe the behaviour only under load?

Comment: What do you mean "dies"? High read times are not lethal.  Is replication staying caught up?  Capture an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` of one of those SELECT queries, and do the same on master.